# Map Win-q to quit in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I'd like to map <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> to quit.

How can I do this in Windows 7? Can I do this in Autohotkey? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you just want to exit the current program, this AutoHotKey script should do the trick:

```
;Activate on Windows key + q
#q::

;Simulate Alt + F4 being pressed
Send !{F4}
```